# Finding Data in JSON with python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, database

I'm so I've the value of the ID "8" and don't  but I want to get the User value XXX-XXX of the Json. Is there a way to get the value? Thank you, if you can help.

```
   users:{
   "XXX-XXX":{
      "Info":{
         "ID":"8",
         "Created": "2021-07-10",
         "Plan": "Basic"}},
   "DDD-DDD":{
       "Info":{
          "ID":"10",
          "Created": "2021-07-11",
          "Plan": "Prime"}}
      }
    }
```

Comment: Use the Json module (https://devtut.github.io/python/json-module.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this naively using pure python and iterating:

```py
def get_user_value(id_):
    for key, user in users.items():
        if user['info']['ID'] == id_:
            return key
    return "Not-Found"
```

If your data is large, however, you may want to explore more optimized approaches.